# I cannot save second Kinect Mesh

Tags: c#, multithreading, save, kinect, mesh

I have a problem saving second Kinect Mesh on my application. I explain it better. I have three Kinects that works perfectly, I see all the data on my application and I can change the viewed image between all of them. But when I try to save automatically the Kinect's information, I only save the firts Kinect Mesh three times, and it is the same Mesh all the time. I put the code below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myLines.Count; i++)
{
    this.ResetFps();
    //this.StopStreams();
    this.sensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[Convert.ToInt32(myLines[i]) - 1];
    this.StartStreams(DepthFormat, ColorFormat);
    ColorMesh mesh = null;
    lock (this.volumeLock)
    {
        this.savingMesh = true;

        if (null == this.volume)
        {
            this.ShowStatusMessage(Properties.Resources.MeshNullVolume);
            return;
        }

        mesh = this.volume.CalculateMesh(1);
   }

   if (null == mesh)
   {
       this.ShowStatusMessage(Properties.Resources.ErrorSaveMesh);
       return;
   }
   BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("kinect" + counter + @".stl", FileMode.Create));
   // Default to flip Y,Z coordinates on save
   Helper.SaveBinaryStlMesh(mesh, writer, true, counter, posicionamiento);

   counter++;

}
this.ShowStatusMessage(Properties.Resources.MeshSaved);
MessageBox.Show("Proceso de digitalizado realizado correctamente.");
```

The problem is when I try to obtain the second Kinect Mesh, but I only have the first Kinect Mesh three times. I can change the Kinects perfectly, but in this code I don't see the Kinect changes until I finish the save process.

Can anyone help me? Thanks! :)

Comment: What's inside `myLines` array?

Comment: the kinect's ID I have to switch. For example: [0,1,1,3,2,2]

Comment: why you used `-1` in the line `this.sensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[Convert.ToInt32(myLines[i]) - 1];` ?